# mysql db backup and restore withought mysqldump. only tar?

Tags: mysql, backup

on my linux system all databases reside in /var/lib/mysql.
Let's say my db is /var/lib/mysql/test1_db

Is it possible and/or advisable to just tar the db directry?
And then use the resulting .tar file to restore it.
Yes, I am stopping mysqld during the process.

If this is ill advised is there something like sql instant file init for linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

1. Stop mysqld
2. tar that directory
3. Start mysqld

It will backup everything except the config file(s) such as `my.cnf`.

LVM snapshot is much faster, but requires setup.

Comment: Why much faster? I still have to stop mysqld - no? Unless you mean to use lvm snapshot itself as a temp backup.

Comment: A LVM snapshot takes seconds.  The `tar` can happen after restarting mysqld.  With Copy-On-Write, mysql's view of the disk is 'independent' of the snapshot.

Comment: I thought you meant the backup is faster. Yes, with lvm -  mysqld down time is much less. One more related question: can I copy a test_db to test2_db and use/access a test2_db as a new instance, or does this involve mysql schema changes? Should this be it's own SE question?

Comment: @gene - please open a new SE Question.  Spell out the _goal_ of the task -- such as "grab a copy of the data and use it in a separate MySQL instance" such as "for QA or performance testing on 'real' data".  This leaves the door open for LVM, Replication, etc, plus some options that will not work, such as sharing the disk (without LVM).